# Suggestion for my first flash gun

Tags: canon, flash

I have Canon 650D camera and mostly doing studio photography as a side income. So far I used my friends what ever the flash guns they had. But Now I'm considering to buy a new flash and after reading some review I thought `Canon Speedlite 600EX-RT` is a good choice. But that is expensive for my budget. Now I'm looking for alternative Brand for this.

Future, I'm planing to buy a full frame camera. So I'm considering this matter too.

You guys have any suggestions?

Comment: See [What features should one look for when selecting a flash?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17722/what-features-should-one-look-for-when-selecting-a-flash) and [What does an expensive flash unit buy over a cheap one?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/33842/what-does-an-expensive-flash-unit-buy-over-a-cheap-one/49946#49946)

Were you planning on using the flash on or off camera? Or both? And what's your approximate budget?  Consider that a flash can change your photography as much as a lens. Why not budget accordingly?

Comment: The Yongnup 565EX II is similar to the 600EX.

Features it shares: Similar guide number (56' instead of 60'), ETTL (the camera can meter the required flash exposure even if the unit is mounted off camera), can be controlled remotely with the 650D's built-in flash unit.

The main feature it lacks is that it cannot act as a master flash to control other units - it can only function as a slave.

Comment: @user29742, actually, the tested guide number on the 565EX puts it between a 430EXII and a 580EXII--zoomed to 35mm (not 105/200 as Canon does), [it's only 36m vs. a 580EXII/600EX-RT's 39m](http://speedlights.net/speedlights-power-index/). It also has no HSS or 360-degree swivel. I'd rate it closer to a 430EXII. Not everybody uses their flash primarily off-camera.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [Canon Speedlite 320EX](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/speedlite_flash_lineup/speedlite_320ex). It is relative cheap and matches price class of your camera body. It is also less powerful than 600EX, but in studio it does not matter so much. If you need powerful flash anyway, then [Metz](https://www.metz.de/en/lighting/flash-units.html) offers a wide choice for far less prices than Canon, but be advised that build quality is considerably lower as well.

Comment: The other nice thing about a 320EX is that if you later decide to get the 600EX-RT, the 600EX can be used to control the 320 via optical sync.  Note, if you get a 600EX-RT later you will end up wanting more of them though.  I started with a 320, got a 600 and I now want two or three more of the 600.

Comment: I don't think it's the case that the build quality is lower for the higher end of the Metz line. (The made-in-Germany models.)