# Is Yongnuo RF 603NII N3 compatible with YN-565EX II Flash Unit without using slave in flash unit

Tags: flash, wireless, yongnuo

I have Yongnuo RF 603NII N3 transceiver (2 pieces). I would like to know whether we can use it without connecting one piece to YN-565EX II Flash Unit i.e. one piece of transceiver will be in my camera hot-shoe, do I need to attach the other piece in the flash unit if the flash unit is YN 565EX II? Or I can use other transceiver as remote trigger in my hand?

I am asking this because both my transceiver and flash unit are Yongnuo

PS: I am yet to buy flash unit.

Thanks in Advance !!

-Nayan Soni

Comment: Here is a post where users are telling that that model of flash works fine in manual mode, but not quite well on ttl wirless mode, so take a look. http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52340/inconsistent-ttl-results-when-flash-used-off-camera-yn565-ex-ii?rq=1 If you dont need the ttl you can go for the 560III.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot set off the YN-565EXII from an RF-603II without attaching another RF-603II to act as a receiver on the foot of the flash.  The YN-565EX has no built-in radio receiver.

However, the RF-603II does not have to be on the camera hotshoe to set off the flash--you can use one in-hand as your transmitter with the test button. The trouble will be syncing it with the camera shutter if you do so. And you could use the S1/S2 "dumb" optical slave modes with your camera's pop-up flash to set off the flash remotely, rather than radio triggers.

If you *really* want a Yongnuo flash with a built-in radio receiver that can be set off by the RF-603II, the YN-560III/YN-560IV is the flash you want, but understand that it is manual only. It cannot do TTL, it has no built-in CLS slave capability, and can only have its power/zoom remotely adjusted if you use the YN-560-TX as your on-camera transmitter.

Comment: Thansk @inkista !! That helped

Answer (score 0):

Edited. No. My response was wrong. It can not be trigged by radio. So I'm editing the post.

You need to use a reciver conected to the flash. But if you need the ttl function you need something like the Yongnuo YN622-TX Wireless ETTL.

If you use the 603 you can only use the manual remote mode on the flash.