# Does the Yongnuo YN 685 flash have a built-in receiver?

Tags: flash, yongnuo

Does the flash YN 685 have a built in receiver? In some places I see that it is written that it does, but other places don't mention it.

Comment: https://youtu.be/iI3A7_NbSwc?t=1m54s

Comment: [What are the Yongnuo flash naming conventions?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47702/what-are-the-yongnuo-flash-naming-conventions) may help.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by a receiver.

The YN-685 has a built-in YN-622 *radio* receiver in it and can be remotely controlled from a Yongnuo YN-622-TX transmitter or YN-622 transceiver with HSS/FP and iTTL. It can also be fired, and have its power, group, and zoom controlled from a YN-560-TX or YN-560IV/YN-660. However, this manual-triggering scheme does not allow for HSS/FP or iTTL as the 622 units do.

The YN-685 has no optical slave capability and *cannot* be used as a Canon near-infrared wireless eTTL slave, a dumb optical slave, or a Canon -RT radio slave.

See also:

- [What are the Yongnuo flash naming conventions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47702/what-are-the-yongnuo-flash-naming-conventions)
- [What features should one look for when selecting a flash?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17722)
- [What does an expensive flash unit buy over a cheap one?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/33842)