# Will the Neewer TT560 speedlite work with my camera?

Tags: flash, wireless-flash, compatibility

I am looking into getting the [Neewer TT560 speedlite](https://support.neewer.com/product/neewer-tt560-speedlite-flash-kit-for-canon-nikon-olympus-fujifilm-and-any-digital-camera-with-a-standard-hot-shoe-mount-includes-1tt560-flash-1universal-portable-softbox-flash-diffuser/) for my Olympus E-PL5, since it has a [transmitter/receiver combination](https://support.neewer.com/product/pt-16gy-16-channels-wireless-remote-flash-speedlite-trigger-for-yongnuo-canon/) that works with it. Is this a viable solution?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your definition of "works."

The Neewer TT560/Godox TT560/Amazon Basics flash is a single-pin manual only flash. It cannot do TTL, HSS, or talk to your camera's flash menus.  All you can tell this flash to do via the single pin on its foot is tell it when to fire.  And that should work on an Olympus camera hotshoe or with radio triggers.  But that's all you can tell it to do.

Flash can be more transformative to your photography than a lens. Budgeting accordingly isn't stupid. Particularly for a first/only speedlight, which you may want to use for [on-camera run'n'gun shooting in TTL](https://neilvn.com/tangents/bounce-flash-photography-wedding-receptions/), as well as [off-camera "Strobist" setups](https://strobist.blogspot.com/2015/04/your-basic-lighting-kit-spin-around.html). I'd highly recommend you consider getting a speedlight that's TTL/HSS compatible with built-in radio remote control and a matching transmitter (e.g., the Godox TT685 II-O or TT350-O and a Godox XPro II-O). That way, you'd have TTL, HSS, and power control both on *and* off the camera hotshoe.

See also:

- [What features should one look for when selecting a flash?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17722/what-features-should-one-look-for-when-selecting-a-flash)
- [What does an expensive flash unit buy over a cheap one?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/33842/what-does-an-expensive-flash-unit-buy-over-a-cheap-one)